# iPhone, the best way to change the background color of the UIAlertView , and button properties?

Tags: iphone

as topic... I want a simple to change the color of AlertView, but after googling, I find it is trouble, anyway, can give a tip on this problem ?
 I also trace the UIAlertView, the structure will be like as follows :

```
CAlertView: 0x6463050; baseClass = UIAlertView; frame = (3.8 175.1; 312.4 129.8); transform = [1.1, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; tag = -1; animations = { transform=<CABasicAnimation: 0x616cfb0>; opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x616d050>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6407f90>>
```

above is base view

subViews as follows:

```
"<UIImageView: 0x6470dc0; frame = (0 0; 284 118); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6470df0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x64649c0; frame = (12 15; 260 0); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6444490>>",
"<UILabel: 0x6454180; frame = (12 22; 260 21); text = 'Submit successfully!'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6453660>>",
"<UIThreePartButton: 0x64690f0; frame = (11 59; 262 43); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x6468800>>"
```

I think that the UIImageView is the background view, I try to change the color of the view, but it does not effect the color of the UIAlertView...

anyone can share a good and simple way to change the color of the alert view ?

thanks for your time .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is app going to be submitted to the app store? If so, I can almost guarentee that Apple will reject your app on Human Interface Guidelines.

You would probably be better creating your own custom version of a `UIAlertView` and showing that instead (you would also have a lot more control over the appearance and behaviour of it).

Comment: hi, Luke, thanks for comment, I had use CAlertView extends the UIAlertView.... if it could be accept by Apple inc ?